# How to implement Social login in my website

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss

I want to allow users to login in my website. they can choose from login using an account created on my website or their facebook or gmail account (or others). Basically I want to do the same as stackoverflow (and many other websites) do when you want to login. I'm using JBOSS AS7 as the application server.
So, since I'm a beginner to J2EE what is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using Social Login ,

As **[Janrain](http://janrain.com/product/social-login/)** says how to do it to your website

SignUp [**here**](http://janrain.com/product/social-login/) and you would be asked to embed a piece of code to your application and it would create the API call.

It is so simple once you start , as they provide free products for basic usage.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Comment here if you have any queries in implementing it